# Native support of wifi usb/pcie

Tags: wireless

I'm building a desktop right now and need to buy a wifi card or wifi usb stick.
Can you tell what kind of wifi cards/sticks work out of the box in ubuntu 13.04? Should I buy a usb wifi or pci-e wifi.

I know a lot of people have troubles with wifi in linux systems.

thanks in advance

Comment: I just got a netgear 6100 and they don't support Ubuntu.  Had to bring it back.

Answer (score 1):

I've started just ordering these.  It saves me a lot of time and headache.  I'd get a PCIe one.

https://www.thinkpenguin.com/catalog/wireless-networking-gnulinux

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "By Card" section of this page [WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)
.